# structure x-axis date as mm/dd/yy using lattice in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want the dates on the x-axis to appear as mm-dd-yy using lattice. Only every month needs to be shown ex: 10/1/2022, 11/1/2022 etc.

I think I may have to use `format(pretty(df$date), "%d-%m-%y")` based on another post but when I try I get an error:
`Error in multiple && !outer : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'`

Here is my code:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

obj1 <- xyplot(Nconc + Sconc ~ date, df, type = "l", main="Title", lwd=2, col= c("red", "steelblue"))
obj2 <- xyplot(CountyCounts ~ date, df, type = "l", lwd=2, col="green")
p <- doubleYscale(obj1, obj2, use.style=FALSE, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
p
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635638400, 
1635811200, 1635897600, 1636070400, 1636416000, 1636502400, 1636588800, 
1636675200, 1636934400, 1637020800, 1637107200, 1637280000, 1637366400, 
1637625600, 1637712000, 1637971200, 1638057600, 1638144000, 1638230400, 
1638316800, 1638403200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Nconc = c(2.63e-05, 2.4e-05, 1.83e-05, 1.47e-05, 2.11e-05, 
    2.09e-05, 3.99e-05, 5.22e-05, 9.17e-06, 2.89e-05, 4.79e-05, 
    1.9e-05, 3.12e-05, 1.81e-05, 5.79e-06, 4.49e-05, 7.61e-06, 
    1.51e-05, 3.61e-05, 1.46e-05, 1.16e-05, 3.53e-05, 0.000232, 
    3.09e-05, 1.31e-06, 1.24e-05, 4.99e-05, 7.76e-05, 0.00016
    ), Sconc = c(2.98e-05, 2.79e-05, 1.75e-05, 2.2e-05, 2.62e-05, 
    2.56e-05, 4.27e-05, 5.6e-05, 1.26e-05, 3.92e-05, 6.11e-05, 
    1.42e-05, 2.53e-05, 2.12e-05, 4.31e-06, 4.57e-05, 9.83e-06, 
    1.07e-05, 3.65e-05, 2.51e-05, 1.23e-05, 2.63e-05, 0.000212, 
    3.99e-05, 1.42e-06, 1.08e-05, 4.09e-05, 7.89e-05, 0.000113
    ), CountyCounts = c(46, 45, 47, 17, 49, 49, 29, 38, 19, 20, 
    30, 25, 38, 24, 19, 27, 27, 30, 39, 17, 11, 23, 21, 19, 21, 
    43, 45, 42, 28)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -29L))
```

Comment: `doubleYscale` isn't an exported object from `lattice`, at least on my machine. you should call external functions specifically using the package its from when asking for help, e.g. `lattice::doubleYscale`

Comment: I have changed it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```r
scales = list(x = list(format = "%d-%m-%y"))
```

to the call creating `obj1` to get the format you want. But to control the locations exactly, you will need to specify them via `at`, e.g.,

```r
scales = list(x = list(at = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-11-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 5), 
                       format = "%d-%m-%y", at = ))
```

You could try playing with `tick.number = 5` (default) to control the locations, and you might get lucky, but there are no guarantees that you will get exactly 1 tick per month that way.